# Autodesk Inventor 2013: Rounding only at specific edge

Tags: design

I am using Autodesk Inventor 2013 and I need to round a component of a device. I want to round the green marked edges, but not the red marked. But when I click "round", then the bottom edge will always be added to the rounding and I cannot de-select it. Any hints how to solve this problem?

[image: Rounding problem in AutoDesk Inventor 2013]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the fillet is reaching the long edge by following the smooth curve around your previously-filleted edges.  The solution is to undo or delete features to get rid of the existing fillets on the left and right sides, then do all the fillets on those sides at once.

Often you need to be strategic in choosing the **order** of chamfering and filleting.  This can get complicated for a real project with lots of different intersecting features!